# Action Listener: sending a text input to an object in Java

Tags: java

I don't know how to send a text input to an object in Java, from a button pressed on an interface using the `action Listener()` method.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Preassessment extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ActionListener {
    static JTextField concept = new JTextField(15);
    JButton enter = new JButton("Enter");
    JLabel conceptLabel = new JLabel("Concept: ");


    public Preassessment() {
        super("Preassessment Sys");
        setSize(350, 180);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    
        JPanel pane = new JPanel();          
        pane.add(conceptLabel);
        pane.add(concept);
        pane.add(enter);
        add(pane);
        enter.addActionListener(this);
        setVisible(true);            
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if(event.getSource() == enter){
            conceptLabel.setText(concept.getText());                
        }   
     }

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        Preassessment preassess = new Preassessment();
        Preassessment agInterface = new Preassessment(); //object to receive the  text         
    }
}
```

Comment: What, precisely, are you trying to do? That would help a lot.

Comment: You might want to look into Observable if I understand what you mean. Else please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not concrete enough. In any case you need a reference to the targetobject somewhere in your code, so one way to do it is:

```
public class Preassessment extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ActionListener {
    static JTextField concept = new JTextField(15);
    JButton enter = new JButton("Enter");
    JLabel conceptLabel = new JLabel("Concept: ");


    public Preassessment(ActionListener listener) {
        super("Preassessment Sys");
        setSize(350, 180);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    
        JPanel pane = new JPanel();          
        pane.add(conceptLabel);
        pane.add(concept);
        pane.add(enter);
        add(pane);
        enter.addActionListener(listener);
        setVisible(true);            
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if(event.getSource() == enter){
            conceptLabel.setText(concept.getText());                
        }   
     }

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        Preassessment agInterface = new Preassessment(); //object to receive the  text  
        Preassessment preassess = new Preassessment(agInterface);       
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The target object is agInterface which is given in the code: Preassessment agInterface = new Preassessment(); do you mean the reference should be different from the one the target object agInterface is created?

Comment: In the long run what i want to do is see if the text input can be passed from the Java object to agent(s) in an agent platform like Jason/Jade. Thank you

Comment: The program was run but error at compilation, see below:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The constructor Preassessment(Preassessment) is undefined

 at Preassessment.main(Preassessment.java:38)

Comment: PLEASE CAN SOME ONE HELP